# Why isn't rs.update, updating my access database? Is it copying to another file instead?

Tags: javascript, sql, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

I have a form that works on IE that connects to a database. This works great. However, when I fill in the text boxes the data does not get transferred to the database. I have checked the field.value and it always equals what I input. The record set is pointing at the right table, as I have checked the names of the rows as it goes through each iteration. However, the data from the boxes never actually gets updated?

```
function parkRecordSet(){
    var conn = accesDB()
    var cmdDI = CreateCommand(conn, "tblPark");
    var rsDI = CreateRecordSet(cmdDI);

    inputData(rsDI)
    UpdateData(conn, rsDI);
}
```

So this part works well. The input data takes in an array that will be passed into the function below as recordData. I put an alert to see if the values I was getting were correct.

```
function AddNewDataToRecordSet(rs, recordData){
    rs.AddNew();

    var myFields = rs.Fields;
    var myEnum = new Enumerator(myFields);
    var indexRecordData = 0;
    var fieldItem;

    myEnum.moveFirst();

    for ( ; !myEnum.atEnd(); myEnum.moveNext() ){
        fieldItem = myEnum.item();
        //alert( "Field Name is: " + fieldItem.Name + " Value is: [" +        fieldItem.Value + "]" + "Attr=" + fieldItem.Attributes)
        if (fieldItem.Attributes & adFldIsNullable) {   //bit-wise test
            fieldItem.Value = recordData[indexRecordData];
            //alert(fieldItem.Value)
            indexRecordData = indexRecordData + 1;
        }  //end of IF

        rs.Fields("ParkName") = "In Process"
    }

    return;
}    

function UpdateData(conn, rs) {
    conn.BeginTrans();
    rs.Update();
    conn.CommitTrans();
    //  Performing the update
    rs.Close();

    return;
}
```

Comment: You begin the recordset transaction just before update. Try moving [BeginTrans](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa227162%28v=VS.60%29.aspx) when first field is being entered. Recall transactions save data externally in a temp location until committing. My guess is there is no data change seen since it occurred before transaction opened.

Comment: Or just get rid of the transaction altogether since it doesn't really provide any benefit.